# Multidimensional interpolation

Tags: language-agnostic, dataset, interpolation, multidimensional-array

Given a dataset of samples in a multi dimensional space (in my case a 4D space) where the samples are present on all the corners of the 4D cube and a substantial amount of samples within this cube but not in a neatly grid. Each sample has an output value next to it's 4D coordinate. The cube has coordinates [0,0,0,0]..[1,1,1,1].

Given a new coordinate (4D) how can I come up with the best interpolated value given these samples? Eg how do I choose the samples to start with, how to interpolate.

As a first guess I would guess that this can be done with a two step process:

1. find the smallest convex pentachoron (4D equivalent of the 3D tetrahedron / the 2D triangle) around the coordinate we need to interpolate.
2. interpolate within this tetrahedron.

Especially step 1 seems quite complex and slow.

Comment: A tetrahedron is 3 dimensional. The 4 dimensional shape that you want is a pentachoron: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentachoron

Comment: @TheBeardMan: Corrected in question. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first approach I'd try.

### Step 1

Find the point's 4 nearest neighbors by Euclidean distance. It's important that these 4 points are linearly independent because next they're used to create a Barycentric coordinate system. Those 4 points become the vertices of your pentachoron (aka 4-simplex).

If nearest-neighbor checks are too slow, try structuring your data into a spatial lookup tree that works in 4D.

### Step 2

Now we need to associate a value with the interpolation point X. Start by deriving X's representation in this new Barycentric coordinate system. This Barycentric coordinate consists of 4 numbers, which collectively describe the relative distance between the interpolation point and each of the 4-simplex's vertices.

[image: Coordinate system conversion]

Normalize the Barycentric coordinate so its components sum to 1.

[image: Normalized Barycentric coordinate]

Each of those 4 simplex vertices are data points and have an output value. Combine those 4 output values into a vector.

[image: Vertex values]

Finally, interpolate by calculating the dot product of the normalized coordinate with the vector of output values.

[image: Interpolated value]

Source: This idea is really just a 4D extension of this gem in middle of the [Barycentric coordinate system page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29#Interpolation_on_a_triangular_unstructured_grid) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Step 2 uses the Barycentric coordinates for interpolation. So as long as we can get within the convex hull of each pentachoron, we will have no discontinuities er on the boundaries we will have the same interpolstion. But the 4 points found in step 1 using the EUcl distance might yield the nearest pentachoron but not the convex one containing the point. Hence we might get discontinuities when two points within the convex hull of of p. A. One uses the coordinate system from p. A and the other from p. B.